# Android: Get and Open Email

Tags: java, android, email

Is it possible to open an email in the standard email client that an android 2.2 phone comes with? I'd like to search emails and then open an email - of course with users permission.

But I can't find any docs and I can't think of any way to open an email by subject.

I would really appreciate any help! I have [**come across this**](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.2_r1.1/com/android/email/activity/MessageList.java) but I can't find these classes in my android library.

Thanks all

Comment: I don't think you can do this at all, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to open an email in the standard email client that an android 2.2 phone comes with?

There is no "standard email client that an android 2.2 phone comes with".

I am not aware of any email clients with documented and supported APIs, beyond `ACTION_SEND`. Certainly neither the AOSP Email application nor Gmail have documented and supported APIs.